# What are the differences between hypersurfaces and manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, submanifold

I understand this question is just about the definitions, but I want to learn the general concepts in the mathematical community.

As far as I know, a hypersurface is a certain type of manifolds that embedded in Euclidean space with codimension 1. Apart from that, manifolds are **locally** homeomorphic to Euclidean space, while hypersurfaces, I guess, are **globally** homeomorphic to Euclidean space. Is that true?

If the concept of topological manifolds is too general, we may just talk about differentiable manifolds. By definition, is a differentiable manifold (of codimension 1) the same to a hypersurface?

**For example, the following curve with a singularity, is it a topological but non-differentiable manifold? Is it a hypersurface?**

[image]

Comment: You may find the definitions in standard texts. Did you do that?

Comment: Is X a topological manifold?

Comment: If we're talking about Riemmanian manifolds (manifolds with a metric), then being embedded as a hyperfurface in an Euclidean space imposes  certain geometrical restrictions on what the metric and curvature of our manifold can be. These are expressed as the Gauss–Codazzi equations.

Comment: "hypersurfaces,..., are globally homeomorphic to euclidean space". if that is the case there is a unique hypersurface for each dimension.

Comment: @ArcticChar I can find the definition of manifolds by chart and atlas in standard textbooks, but no such a text relates it to hypersurfaces.

Comment: @Garmekain So my guess is not true? I cannot find a serious definition of hypersurfaces, though such a definition exists for manifolds.

Comment: @user3257842 Do you mean hypersurfaces are in a subset of Riemmanian manifolds with some restrictions on metric and curvature?

Comment: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. A hypersurface of $M$ is an embedded submanifold $N$ in $M$ of codimension one. That is, $\dim M-\dim N = 1$. You can find it in p.99 of Lee's Introduction to smooth manifold.

Comment: @Analysis Newbie Yes. Consider a Riemmanian manifold of dimension $n$ . If we can embed it in an Euclidean  space of dimension $n$, that means it's flat. Its curvature vanishes. Manifolds that can be embedded in an Euclidean space of dimension $n+1$ (as hypersurfaces) have weaker restrictions on metric and  curvature (they don't have to be flat), but restrictions still exist. As the dimension of the Euclidean space grows,  the restrictions needed for Riemann manifolds of a given fixed dimension to be embeddable in it weaken.

Comment: The smallest dimension of Euclidean space in which you can (locally) embed any $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and is called the Janet dimension.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks! It sounds like a hypersurface is always a smooth manifold, so we don't need to emphases that there is a "smooth" hypersurface?

Answer (score 2):

A big issue here is how does your curve get its topology? Probably you are tacitly assuming the topology is inherited from the topology on the plane, i.e., the subspace topology.

But there are other ways to define a topology. We can present a curve parametrically so that it is homeomorphic to ${\bf R}$, but not in the subspace topology. Study this section of a wiki: [Immersed curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold#Immersed_submanifolds).  The image there is meant to show how this can happen.  [image]

Now let's return to your question at an intuitive level. If the topology of the curve in your question is inherited from the embedding plane, then it looks like no neighborhood of the origin is homeomorphic to an interval, so this would not be a one-dimensional manifold. Is the curve a hypersurface? I suspect you generated the curve by implicitly plotting an equation of the form $f(x,y)=0$, perhaps $y^2-x^4(1-x^2)=0$. If so, then yes--this would be a hypersurface. But I can envision defining the curve parametrically in such a way that the curve is a manifold homeomorphic to ${\bf R}$, but not in the subspace topology.